# Dynamic route request render in express framework

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I want to try some dynamic routing. I'm using express framework for my node js server. here is my HTML Code

```
<a href="/views/adminpanel?url={{mMenu.WebAddress}}" ng-click="Description(mMenu.WebAddress)">{{mMenu.MenuName}}</a>
```

In client side

```
$scope.Description = function(url)
    {

        $http({'method' : 'get', 'url' : '/views/adminpanel/'+url; 
         }).success(function(data)
        {

        }).
        error(function(data){

        })

    }
```

And In server side,

```
 app.get('/views/adminpanel/url', function(req, res) {

    res.render('views/adminpanel/url');


  });
```

This is our routing process. How could I route request properly and where is my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client
`$http({'method' : 'get', 'url' : '/views/adminpanel/'+url;`

Server `app.get('/views/adminpanel/url'`

unless the client url variable is = `url` then this will not match. I believe you want something like this exposing `url` as a param in the uri.

```
app.get('/views/adminpanel/:url', function(req, res) {
  res.render('views/adminpanel/'+req.params.url);
});
```